# Nested statements in sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite, nested-statement

I'm using the sqlite3 library in c++ to query the database from *.sqlite file. can you write a query statement in sqlite3 like:

```
char* sql = "select name from table id = (select full_name from second_table where column = 4);"
```

The second statement should return an id to complete the query statement with first statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just make sure that the nested query doesn't return more than one row. Add a LIMIT 1 to the end of the nested query to fix this. Also make sure that it always returns a row, or else the main query will not work.

If you want to match several rows in the nested query, then you can use either `IN`, like so:

```
char* sql = "select name from table WHERE id IN (select full_name from second_table where column = 4);"
```

or you can use `JOIN`:

```
char* sql = "select name from table JOIN second_table ON table.id = second_table.full_name WHERE second_table.column = 4"
```

Note that the `IN` method can be very slow, and that `JOIN` can be very fast, if you index on the right columns

Comment: Adding a LIMIT 1 may be obscuring other faults; perhaps his query is only supposed to ever return a single row.  You might want (!) an error if it doesn't.

Comment: It returns the 'full_name' from the table matching column 4. I guess I would need to use something like a for loop to get each 'full_name'.

Answer (score 1):

On a sidenote, you can use SQLiteadmin (http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) to view the database and make queries directly in it (useful for testing etc).