# Nested query is not supported in SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I use an SQLite database on my iPhone application and i need to perform a task that require a nested query. However, my query seems not working, i have googled it and i found that SQLite doesn't support Subquerys.
Is there any solution?

**EDIT:**
This is the query that doesn't work for me:

```
select count(*) from quiz where theme=(select id from theme where nom="Houses") and etat=0;
```

Comment: SQLite supports subqueries. Can you post an example of a query that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Nick, i have edited my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use joins instead of nested query, that will work.

for reference please check this...

[Nested statements in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256194/nested-statements-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 5):

If the subquery `(select id from theme where nom="Houses")` returns multiple rows,
the `theme =` wont work. You must use `theme IN` instead.

```
select count(*) from quiz where theme IN (select id from theme where nom="Houses") and etat=0;
```